# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while setting up JUnits for SnapLogic custom snaps

Tags: java, junit, guice, etl, snaplogic

I want to create my own snap in SnapLogic .

I downloaded the sample project by running the following:

```
$ mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://maven.clouddev.snaplogic.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/master/
```

But, when I build this project I get the following error that fails in the JUnit:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin\java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:53596,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\kqvx285\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.snaplogic.snaps.TwoInputsTwoOutputsTest
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53596', transport: 'socket'

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.snaplogic.snap.api.OutputViewsImpl.add(Lcom/snaplogic/snap/view/OutputView;)

V

at com.snaplogic.snap.test.harness.TestResultImpl.addOutputView(TestResultImpl.java:116)
at com.snaplogic.snap.test.harness.TestSetupImpl.addOutputView(TestSetupImpl.java:393)
at com.snaplogic.snap.test.harness.SnapExecutor.createOutputViewFor(SnapExecutor.java:845)
at com.snaplogic.snap.test.harness.SnapExecutor.evaluate(SnapExecutor.java:426)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53596', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you could reference which materials you are using for your custom snap development.
Can you make sure if you have followed all the instructions on the documentation: http://developer.snaplogic.com

Comment: Yes I used that documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to an out-of-date dependency. Could you try removing the `com/snaplogic` folder in your local Maven repository and then rebuilding?

e.g. `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/snaplogic/`